# Create a percentage formula with using a case when expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a formula for percentage while using a case when statement. I need numerator to acknowledge the amount of clients with a form_one_answer answer and the visit type being 'Form Questions'which is why I came up with this SQL formula:

```
 (CASE WHEN "Customer"."customer_id" IS NOT NULL AND "Form_Questions"."question_one_answer" IS NOT NULL AND "Visittype"."visittype" = 'Form Questions' THEN 1 END) AS NUMER
```

I also need the dominator to acknowledge the total amount of clients with visit type being 'Form Questions' which I ended up making this SQL formula:

```
(CASE WHEN "Customer"."customer_id" IS NOT NULL AND ""Visittype"."visittype" = 'Form Questions' THEN 1 END) AS DENOM
```

What I am trying to do is get the total amount of clients who answered the question for question 1 and divide by the total amount of people who did the visit type 'form questions'. The question is listed in the 'form questions' visit but it is not required to be answered so not everybody who did the 'form questions' visit will answer that question. I did try to divide the numerator from the denominator then multiply it by 100 afterwards but it only leaves me with 100. I'm not sure why. This makes me wonder if I need the SUM() in here in order to consider the total amount of clients who answered the question for question 1 then divide by the total amount of people who did the visit type 'form questions'

This is how I did the SQL:

```
 (((CASE WHEN "Customer"."customer_id" IS NOT NULL AND "Form_Questions"."question_one_answer" IS NOT NULL AND "Visittype"."visittype" = 'Form Questions' THEN 1 END)/(CASE WHEN "Customer"."customer_id" IS NOT NULL AND ""Visittype"."visittype" = 'Form Questions' THEN 1 END)) *100) AS PERCENTAGE
```

I did try converting the case when number into a float but I ran into errors with it. I did not see anything online where I could convert the 1 into a float while in the case when statement. I also did try using the SUM() for the numerator and denominator but ran into incorrect syntax errors and needing to use group by in order to use SUM(). I will say I am not sure if using the group by would be what I need to do in this situation. Last thing I tried was a subquery but I was having the same issues.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT distinct
   "Form_Questions"."question_one_answer",    
   "Visittype"."visittype",    
   "CustomerVisit"."Visit_start_time",    
   "Customer"."age",    
   "Customer"."customer_id",    
   (CASE WHEN "Customer"."customer_id" IS NOT NULL AND "Form_Questions"."question_one_answer" IS NOT NULL AND "Visittype"."visittype" = 'Form Questions' THEN 1 END) AS NUMER,     
   (CASE WHEN "Customer"."customer_id" IS NOT NULL AND ""Visittype"."visittype" = 'Form Questions' THEN 1 END) AS DENOM    
FROM "dbo"."Customer" AS "Customer"    
INNER JOIN "dbo"."CustomerVisit" AS "CUSTOMERVISIT"
ON (
    "Customer"."customer_id" = "CustomerVisit"."customer_id"
)
INNER JOIN "dbo"."Form_Questions"
ON (
   CUSTOMERVISIT"."customervisit_id" = "Form_Questions"."customervisit_id"
)
INNER JOIN "dbo"."VisitType" AS "VISITTYPE"
ON (
   "CUSTOMERVISIT"."visittype_id" = "VISITTYPE"."visittype_id"
    )
WHERE  "Visittype"."visittype" = 'Form Questions'
```

Here is some data to use for this:

| customer_id | question_one_answer | visittype | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | yes | Form Questions | 6 |
| 00002 | no | Form Questions | 18 |
| 00003 | *null* | Form Questions | 17 |

The result I would like to get is where the there is a new column that is a fraction like what is being divided and then another new column with the percentage total. Something like this:

| fraction | percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 2/3 | 66% |

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Make it easy to assist you - simplify!

Comment: @jarlh do you mean an example of what I want the conclusion to be or showing some example data to work with or both?

Comment: As in make it so that we can *run* your SQL provide consumable sample data, show us your expected results. You talk about getting the total here, however, there's no aggregation so where is this total coming from?

Comment: As a side note, you don't need *any* of the parentheses you have on your attempt.

Comment: *minimal* as in, as small an example as you can which demonstrates the issue, *reproducible* as in provide a small set of sample data in consumable format (e.g. DDL+DML) and show your desired results (as tabular data) for the provided sample data.

Comment: Will edit that information in shortly.

Comment: Using *conditional aggregation* you can do something like `100e0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN {answered question 1} THEN 1 END) / NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN {responded to survey} THEN 1 END), 0) AS Q1Percentage`. The `100e0` both scales the result by 100 and forces the calculation to be done using the `FLOAT` data type. The `NULLIF()` protects against division by zero - If the numerator is zero, it is changed to NULL and the overall result also becomes NULL.  Sometimes it is best not to scale the value in the query and leave it as a fractional value. The presentation layer can scale and format the result.

Comment: And lose the `DISTINCT`. Use `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be fair to say that the query asks, "What proportion of customers who came to the *form questions* visit answered *question one*?". If so, then *customer_visit* is the driving table. From what can be gleaned from the SQL, I think it would be fair to assume that *customervisit_id* is the primary key of the *customer_visit* table. That relation has a foreign key, *visittype_id*, to the *visittype* table and can be filtered early in the joins. The *form_questions* table seems to have at least two fields: *customervisit_id* and *question_one_answer*. From the wording surrounding the code, the latter either has a value or *is null*. To my mind, and without seeing the data, only three tables are required to return the required result set (a scalar): *customer_visit*, *visittype* and *form_questions*. **The code below assumes a customer can only have one *form questions* visit and that there are no orphaned visits...**

```
select
sum(t.row_calcs) proportion_who_answered_question_one
from
(
 select
 100.0*case when fq.question_one_answer is not null then 1 end
  /count(*) over() row_calcs
 from customer_visit cv
 join visittype v
 on cv.visittype_id=v.visittype_id
 and v.visittype='form questions'
 join form_questions fq
 on cv.customervisit_id=fq.customervisit_id
) t;
```

Comment: I've edited this from my first posted answer as, on reflection, it is more efficient to use the _customer_visit_ table as the driving table.  All of this is based on some pretty broad assumptions regarding the data structure, but I was trying to see how far the question could be fulfilled from the description and accompanying code.

Answer (score 0):

If you select all customer visits of type 'Form Questions' then `COUNT(*)` will give you the total number of visits. `question_one_answer` is NULL when question #1 was not answered in the visit, otherwise it is NOT NULL. So, `COUNT(question_one_answer)` will give you the number of visits where question #1 was answered.

```
SELECT
   CONCAT(COUNT(fq.question_one_answer), '/', COUNT(*)) AS fraction,
   COUNT(fq.question_one_answer) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM dbo.customervisit cv
JOIN dbo.form_questions fq ON fq.customervisit_id = cv.customervisit_id
WHERE cv.visittype_id = 
        (SELECT visittype_id FROM dbo.visittype WHERE visittype = 'Form Questions');
```